# How to store text entered in unknown ammount of textareas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I think my case is a bit harder than the other I saw here on SO. Here I have an unknown amount of `textarea`'s, that were appended via [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to a placeholder in the website. The goal is to display all of the `textarea`'s with the entered information the next time the user connects to the website. The jQuery script uses the following template for appending the elements:
**HTML**

```
<div class="note">
    <button onclick="this.parentElement.remove()"><i class="ci-pro ci-trash3"></i></button>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

(`<i class="ci-pro ci-trash3"></i>` is used for displaying an icon from CloudianIconsPro)

Using [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com) I made `.note` [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable) and [resizeable](http://jqueryui.com/resizeable).
What I managed to do so far is the following:
**JavaScript** with *jQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("notes.list")) { //check if there is something in the local storage
        $("#notes-container").html(localStorage.getItem("notes.list"));
        // #notes-container is the placeholder
    }
    function cacheNotes() {
        var list = $("#notes-container").html();
        //get the content from the placeholder
        localStorage.setItem("notes.list", list);
        //save to the local storage
        setTimeout(cacheNotes, 2000);
        //repeat the proccess
    }
    setTimeout(cacheNotes, 1000);
});
```

The result of the code above was the following:

> - All `div`'s were in their places (as dragged by the user)
> - All `div`'s kept their size (as resized by the user)
> - The `textarea`'s were empty

I can tell the textareas were empty, because I "cached" only the **HTML** code inside the placeholder. I also thought that I can not set a hundred of other local storages for caching the text from each `textarea`.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do it to loop through all `<div .notes>`s available in the page, then save the information you needed to an array, `stringify` the array then save to `localStorage`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var saveData = function() {
    // loop through all notes
    var tobeCached = [];
    $(".note").each(function() {
      // store elements index
      var obj = {
        // get .note index
        index: $(this).index(),
        // get .note name
        name: $(this).attr("name")
      };

      // get the value of the textarea in it
      obj["value"] = $(this).find("textarea").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
      }).get()[0] // map returns an array;

      tobeCached.push(obj);
    });

    // save it
    localStorage.setItem("cachedData", JSON.stringify(tobeCached));
    alert('data saved');
  };

  var loadData = function() {
    var cached = localStorage.getItem("cachedData");

    if (cached) {
      cached = JSON.parse(cached);

      // loop through each cached data 
      for (var i = 0; i < cached.length; i++) {
        var cachedItem = cached[i];
        // find the note
        var note = $(document).find(".note[name='" + cachedItem.name + "']");

        // just make sure that note was found
        if (note) {
          // find the note that contains name and reorder it
          $(note).insertBefore($(".note").eq((cached[i].index) + 1));
          // then find a textarea and change its value
          $(note).find("textarea").val(cached[i].value);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  $("#save").click(function() {
    saveData();
  });

  // make .items sotable
  $(".items").sortable();

  // call load data by default
  loadData();
});
```

```css
.note {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
}

.note:hover {
  
  border: 1px solid red;
}

textarea {
   width: 90%;
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
   <div class="note" name="note-1">
   1
      <textarea></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="note" name="note-2">
   2
      <textarea></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="note" name="note-3">
   3
      <textarea></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="note" name="note-4">
   4
      <textarea></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="note" name="note-5">
   5
      <textarea></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="note" name="note-6">
   6
      <textarea></textarea>
   </div>
</div>
<button id="save">
save
</button>
```

[here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/jo6u3412/4/)

hope that helps

Comment: Can you please post the js fiddle code as a SO code snippet?

Comment: @MonaLisa sorry but `localStorage` is not allowed to be used on snippet

Comment: To test the fiddle example just click the save button to save the data, to load just simply relaunch the code.

Comment: please notice the option to remove the textarea's in the code of my question. Also, via another function (addNote) the user is able to add more of the containers (.note) with textarea.
Storing their values works perfect, but what about storing the containers as well? Maybe by clicking "save" it should also save the placeholder of the containers ("#notes-container").

Comment: @MonaLisa hello I modified the the answer based on your input, `the option to remove a .note textarea` is not necessary to be handled as the `save` function I created loops through each available `.note` in the page `which means removed ones are not included`. I updated the answer and the fiddle to save the `<div .note>` position as well and reposition it according to where it was when modified.

Comment: I do not know why, but it is not working. I made it so it autosaves every 2 seconds and the value of the localStorage is "[]".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153590/discussion-between-mona-lisa-and-masterpreenz).

Answer (score 2):

You're saving the HTML of an entire container, that contains the textareas.

First of all, it's not very efficient, and secondly, it won't work.
The HTML doesn't change when you type in the textarea, the value property does, which is what you want to save.

I notice you have an option to remove textareas, so you need to do something to store the order of textareas as well, unless you keep that state on reload.

Something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("notes_list")) {
    var html   = localStorage.getItem("notes_html");
    var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes_list"));

    $("#notes-container").html(html);

    $.each(result, function(_, data) {
      $("#" + data.index).text(data.value);
    });
  } else {
    $("#notes-container textarea").each(function(i) {
      this.id = 'notes_' + i;
    });
  }

  function cacheNotes() {
    var list = $("#notes-container textarea").map(function(_, item) {
      return { index: item.id, value: item.value };
    }).get();

    localStorage.setItem("notes_list", JSON.stringify(list));
    localStorage.setItem("notes_html", $("#notes-container").html());
    setTimeout(cacheNotes, 2000);
  }
  setTimeout(cacheNotes, 1000);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/L5u6pqmd/)

Comment: This looks fantastic, but there is one problem. I've got no idea how to hook this into my source because the code you wrote is complicated for me and I also need to add the part of the code I wrote in my question that also stores the markup in the placeholder. With fewer words: I need to store both the markup and the textareas' value.

Comment: @MonaLisa - I've edited to try and do what you wanted, where it stores everything, icluding the values etc.

Comment: no idea why, but it seems to be not working. I am not sure if the information I missed to include in my question would change anything, but here it is: The user is appending the containers ".note" via an addNote() function, so there might be none if the user hasn't added any.<br> If this does change how things work, please tell me so I will update my question.